# How to use newsletter subscription checkbox on any section of MyAccount in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to implement the functionality which we get in the My Account section as shown in the screenshot.(Default functionality, but I want to use it in some custom phtml file. )

[image]

I am using the following code to implement this in My account section of the Magento as I have some design customization in phtml file.This functionality I want to provide to the Logged in customers only.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/newsletter')->setTemplate('customer/form/newsletter.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

But when I click on save I am redirected to 404 page.
Please suggest.

Comment: I think u cant use this in every page. Newsletter subscription needs email ID. So if the customer is not logged IN, then how will you get the Email ID. So only it is redirecting to 404 Page

Comment: @PavanKumar Please see the updated question.I had mentioned wrongly            all pages I want this functionality in the My Account section only.

Comment: Instead of $this did u try with Mage::app() ??

Comment: One more thing, is your layout file contains block of it, Like <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>.. You must add this to your layout section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/newsletter')->setTemplate('customer/form/newsletter_custom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Then I copied all the content of the `\template\customer\form\newsletter.phtml` to the `newsletter_custom.phtml` and changed the

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

To

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>newsletter/manage/save/" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

So no 404 error coming now.